# why isnt this php working, i get undefined index...?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to upload an image to the server.

I hava a form with a couple of inputs...
INSIDE this form, I have an Iframe which contains another form for the upload, this because I dont want the original form to submit().

The original form basically:

```
      <form> ...... bla bla bla alot of inputs....<iframe src="pic_upload.html"></iframe></form>
```

Here is pic_upload.html:

```
      </head>
      <body><form name="pic_form" id="pic_form" action="bincgi/imageUpload.php" method="post" target="pic_target"><input name="pic_file" type="file" id="pic_file" size="35" onchange="this.form.submit();"></form><div id="pic_target" name="pic_target" style="width:80px; height:80px;"></div></body>
      </html>
```

Here is imageUpload.php:

```
      <?php
      $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
      //echo $destination_path;
      $result = 0;
      $target_path = $destination_path . basename($_FILES['pic_file']['name']);
      if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      $result = 1;
      }
      ?>
```

I get this error: Undefined index: pic_file on line 5 in imageUpload.php

ALSO, if I get this to work, is there a good way to display the uploaded image inside the target of the form?

Thanks alot!
PS: I will add javascript to the tags because maybe thats what I need here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget about form attribute

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 1):

The form needs to be like this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="__URL__" method="POST">
```

Check out [this PHP.net documentation](http://is.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to test if `$_FILES` has an item with the key `pic_file`. So use the `isset` function to do so:

```
$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
//echo $destination_path;
$result = 0;
if (isset($_FILES['pic_file'])) {
    $target_path = $destination_path . basename($_FILES['pic_file']['name']);
    if (@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        $result = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so now it doesnt give any errors, but a blank screen opens...and the image is not uploaded??